# Check if multi directory exists

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def checkandremoveboth():
    dirpath = "C:\Adialapps\CRMV3', 'C:\Adialapps\CRMV2"
if os.path.exists(dirpath) and os.pathisdir(dirpath):
    shutil.rmtree(dirpath)
```

This formatting looks correct but not working?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What error message or unexpected behavior do you see?

Comment: Also, you have a race condition here. You check that the path exists but there's no reason it can't be removed by a different process after the check, but before the script executes `shutil.rmtree`. It would be better to use a `try`/`except` block to just delete the directories and catch any errors. You can also call it with `ignore_errors=true` to suppress exceptions if the path doesn't exists, although you do risk hiding other errors, like incorrect permissions.

Answer (score 2):

```
import os, shutil

def remove_dirs(dirs):
    for dir in dirs:
        shutil.rmtree(dir, ignore_errors=True) # https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree

dirs = ["C:\Adialapps\CRMV3', 'C:\Adialapps\CRMV2"]
remove_dirs(dirs)
```

Comment: Did you mean to keep his mismatched parentheses?

Comment: I couldn't fully understand the the original code, but the problem seemed clear.

Answer (score 2):

A better-way and clean way with loop rather than checking each path manually .

```
import os

def check_and_remove(pathsList):
    for path in pathsList:
        if os.path.exists(path) and os.path.isdir(path):
            shutil.rmtree(dir,ignore_errors=True)
            print("Deleted")
        else:
            print(path, " directory not found")


dirs_to_delete = [
    'C:\Adialapps\CRMV3',
    'C:\Adialapps\CRMV2'
]

check_and_remove(dirs_to_delete)
```